# how to display wordpress title with conditional if else?

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a title section in WordPress theme option for site title. I want that if that field is empty then it will display wp_title regular title with front page condition or the field is fill up then the title will display what written in the field. I tried this

```
    <title> 
    <?php if (is_home()) {
                  $website_title = ot_get_option('website_title');
                  if (isset($website_title) && $website_title != "") {
                  echo $website_title;
                   } else {
                   is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); bloginfo('name'); 
                   } 
              } else { 
              is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); bloginfo('name');  
            } 
     ?>
   </title>
```

But this code works great in localhost of my computer and when i upload this code in website online it works as regular wp_title, no change happen from theme option. But from localhost theme option change is correctly.
If someone any idea please.